# Getting CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED when opening video file with VIDEO.js -

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

The error only happens when i try to view the website(video) over the internet.
Everything works perfectly when i am running locally in visual studio and it also works perfectly when i remote desktop into the production webserver where i published the site to and browse to the site locally there.

If i had to guess it seems like something is timing out when it goes over the internet or maybe there is something on our firewall preventing the movie from streaming to me from the production webserver. I doubt the firewall is the issue because i can view other videos streamed with video.js from other sources.

My developertools console window shows this (I tried to post a screenshot but i didnt have enough rep points):
GET http://166.62.34.149/Videos/Walgreens_8700SKedzieAve.m4v net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTEDvideo.js:118 s.loadvideo.js:65 Tvideo.js:75 s.loadVideo.aspx?VideoName=Walgreens_8700SKedzieAve.m4v:59 (anonymous function)video.js:36 s.Hvideo.js:28 t.a.t.ua.extend.ivideo.js:6 dvideo.js:57 t.Player.t.a.extend.ivideo.js:6 dvideo.js:2 tVideo.aspx?VideoName=Walgreens_8700SKedzieAve.m4v:57 (anonymous function)

here is my code:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var videoName;
        //videojs.autoSetup();
        videoName = document.getElementById('lblVideoName').innerHTML;
        videojs('my_video_1', {}, function(){
            this.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: "/Videos/" + videoName });
            this.load();
            this.play();
        });
        videojs('my_video_1').ready(function () {
        // Store the video object
        var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
        var aspectRatio = 478 / 850;

        function resizeVideoJS() {
            var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
            myPlayer.width(width).height(width * aspectRatio);

        }

        resizeVideoJS();
        window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;
    });


        function PausePlayer() {
            var myPlayer = videojs('my_video_1');
            myPlayer.pause();
        };
</script>
```

I have set my IIS mime type, so that isnt the issue.  Any help you have provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you found a solution on this issue in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old oner but just to let you know that I came across this with our website and after digging deep into mime types, changing sources, removing cache and so on, a simple options --> advanced --> "Reset" made everything work fine.

This will obviously only be the case if you can test it working on other PC's somewhere else to confirm all the mime types and video work in the first place.

Hope this is of help to someone in the future as it was the top Google result for me.

Regards
Liam

Comment: Can you please detail a little bit more, how/where did you use "Reset" ? It is a header, a tag property, etc ?

Comment: Hi @Victor this was 3 years ago now, but I believe I meant a reset within internet explorer as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings

Comment: Thanks for the rsp ! In my case I have to change the headers the server is returning - I receive _video/mpeg_ and the file extension is _.mp4_ (in case somebody else is reading this and may help the hint)